# On using $A = CDC^{-1}$ and $A=C^{-1}DC$ for diagonalizing a matrix and finding $D$

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I am studying matrix diagonalization and I have a few doubts. We know that a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if there exists an invertible matrix $C$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A = CDC^{-1}$ is diagonal. Does $A=C^{-1}DC$ also hold true? I've done a few calculations and it seems like so but would like confirmation.

To find $D$, I first find $C$ with the diagonalization method. Then, $D=CAC^{-1}$. After I find $D$, then: $A=CDC^{-1}$. Am I missing something? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes sure, the $C$ in one is the $C^{-1}$ in the other and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a linear transformation $T$. In one basis (which I will call $a$) this linear transformation is represented by the matrix $A$. In a different basis (which I will call $d$), the same linear transformation is represented by $D$.

The matrix $C$ takes the components of any vector as expressed in one of these bases and translates it to the other base. Sandwitching a matrix (representing some linear transformation) between $C$ and $C^{-1}$ will take the components of that matrix and translate that to the matrix that represents the same linear transformation in the other base.

When you write $A = CDC^{-1}$, then that means that you have chosen $C$ to be the matrix that takes in the components of vectors expressed in $d$ and spits out the components of vectors expressed in $a$. When you write $A = C^{-1}DC$, then that means that you have chosen $C$ to be matrix that takes in  vectors expressed in $a$ and spits out vectors expressed in $d$. These are different $C$'s and should never be used in the same context the way I have done in this paragraph. You have to make a single choice and then stick with it.

Usually, when diagonalizing, it is most immediate and therefore most convenient to choose $C$ so that its columns are the eigenvectors of $T$, expressed in the basis $a$ (the so-called "eigenvectors of $A$"). This means that we happen to go with the *first* option above. This means that $A = CDC^{-1}$. Note that this also means
$$
A = CDC^{-1}\\
AC = CDC^{-1}C\\
AC = CD\\
C^{-1}AC = C^{-1}CD = D
$$
so that we have $D = C^{-1}AC$, not the other way around.

Comment: When my teacher assistant wrote: given a matrix $A$ find S such that $SAS^{-1}$ is diagonal then does that mean he made a typo? Because it should then probably be $S^{-1}AS$.

Comment: @Cesare Not necessarily. It just means you need to invert the customary $C$. So after finding the eigenvectors of $A$, there is an additional step of calculation before you're done. It might even be intentional, to check up on who's keeping track of everything

Answer (score 1):

If you take $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $C=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\\mathrm{i}&\mathrm{-i}\end{pmatrix}$ and

$$C^{-1}DC = \begin{pmatrix}0&\mathrm{i}\\\mathrm{i}&0\end{pmatrix} \neq CDC^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc it does. $C^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1&-\mathrm{i}\\1&\mathrm{i}\end{pmatrix}$ and $C^{-1}AC = \begin{pmatrix} -\mathrm{i}&0\\0&\mathrm{i}\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have $D=CAC^{-1}$, now how can you find $A$?

Multiply with $C$ to the right:
$$DC = CAC^{-1}C\\[0.2cm]
DC = CA$$

and $C^{-1}$ to the left:

$$C^{-1}DC = C^{-1}CA\\[0.2cm]\\C^{-1}DC = A$$

You seem confused that since you can choose whether you start with

$$D = CAC^{-1}$$ or $$D = C^{-1}AC$$

it does not mean that you can switch between these once you have chosen one of them.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not: the identity $C^2DC^{-2}=D$ for a generic diagonal matrix $D$ and a generic invertible matrix $C$ is not a thing.

Comment: I don't think I wrote that $CDC^{-1}=D$, rather $CDC^{-1}=A$

Comment: What is meant by "is not a thing"?

Comment: @coffeemath Supermarkets are things, flying broomsticks are not a thing.

Comment: @Cesare I did not write $CDC^{-1}=D$ either.

Comment: Yes, but a more mathematical explanation of how OP's steps go wrong would be good.

Comment: @coffeemath I guess in that $D=CAC^{-1}\Rightarrow A=CDC^{-1}$ passage instead of $C^{-1}DC=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\-i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ its eigenvalues are $\mp 1$  so $$D=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end {pmatrix}$$ and the doiagonalizinfg matrix is $C=\begin{pmatrix} -i & i \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then
$$C^{-1} D C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$CDC^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$